# Generating instances for n-depth structures?

Tags: haskell

By `n-depth structure` I mean some structure that nests one kind of structure `n` times, for example `[[a]]` is a 2-depth list.

I was randomly thinking about an instance of `Functor`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` for a 3-depth list (`[[[a]]]`) today, and found some regularity as you can see below:

```
instance Functor [[[]]] where
    fmap f n = fmap (fmap (fmap f)) n

instance Foldable [[[]]] where
    foldMap f n = foldMap (foldMap (foldMap f)) n

instance Traversable [[[]]] where
    sequenceA n =
        let fz = \z -> sequenceA z
            fy = \y -> sequenceA (fmap fz y)
            fx = \x -> sequenceA (fmap fy x)
        in  fx n
```

I think this can be automated typesafely in some way, not only for `[]` but any structures that have these instances (like `Vector`), and not only 3-depth but any depths as long as it's more than zero.

I think something like `data Depth = One | Succ Depth` will be used for compile-time depth calculation, but beyond that, I have no idea how it goes. Do you think this is actually possible? How would you implement it?

Comment: what type has `f` in `let g f = fmap f [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`?

Comment: `[[[]]]` looks ill-kinded.

Comment: My friend, You have just discovered FREE MONADS! Sorta. http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are quite nice in that they present a single (parameterized) data type that can handle structures of any depth; however, they use advanced type system features to achieve this. On the other hand, there are quite simple features that can be used instead to achieve the same thing, and with greater flexibility. The basic idea is to define functor composition once and for all:

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getComposition :: f (g a) }
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose v) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) v)
```

One can similarly define instances for `Foldable` and `Traversable` with no extensions. Then you get one-fold, two-fold, and three-fold nesting as, e.g.

```
type DepthOneList = []
type DepthTwoList = Compose [] []                -- = Compose [] DepthOneList
type DepthThreeList = Compose [] (Compose [] []) -- = Compose [] DepthTwoList
```

and these have the requisite `Functor`, `Foldable`, and `Traversable` operations. Moreover, you have great flexibility here; you need not have the same functor at every depth but could have for example

```
type Mixed = Compose [] (Compose Vector [])
```

with no problem. If it is really needed, one can happily unroll type-level nats into this more structured type-level object (though of course this requires similar extensions to the ones used in other answers):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds    #-}
data Nat = Z | S Nat
type family IterCompose (n :: Nat) (f :: * -> *) :: * -> * where
    IterCompose Z f = Identity
    IterCompose (S n) f = Compose f (IterCompose n f)
```

But this type-level translation is, in most cases, less flexible, less usable, and less readable than just writing the composed type by hand, so I would consider this part the "uninteresting" part in some sense.

A pre-implemented functor composition operation is available from Hackage in the [TypeCompose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose) package and, perhaps more canonically, in [transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers).

Answer (score 5):

What you're talking about is essentially composition of functors (*n*-fold self-composition, specifically, but that doesn't really matter).

Indeed [such compositions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Functor-Compose.html) can be made automatically instances of the `Functor`, `Applicative`, `Foldable` and `Traversable` class. Also, you can have stacks of [monad transformers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.3.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html) (which are essentially an alternative approach to functor composition).

To make it *n*-fold with the same functor, you need a suitable wrapper.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, GADTs, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data NCompose :: Nat -> (* -> *) -> * -> * where
  Singly :: f x -> NCompose (S Z) f x
  Multiplie :: NCompose n f (f x) -> NCompose (S n) f x

instance Functor (NCompose Z f) where
  fmap _ _ = undefined -- safe, since there's no constructor for `NCompose Z f x`
instance (Functor f, Functor (NCompose n f)) => Functor (NCompose (S n) f) where
  fmap f (Singly q) = Singly $ fmap f q
  fmap f (Multiplie q) = Multiplie $ fmap (fmap f) q
```

Answer (score 5):

We can do this with the current GHC support for dependent typing. Preliminaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Singletons -- from "singletons" package
import Data.Nat        -- from my "singleton-nats" package
```

From [`Data.Nat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singleton-nats) we get a natural number type that can be used on the type level with the `DataKinds` extension. We also get its [singleton](https://github.com/goldfirere/singletons/) type,  which enables us to pattern match on `Nat` runtime. We use the `Z` and `S` constructors in the type level, and the `SZ` and `SS` constructors on the term level, for the zero and successor constructors respectively.

We define iteration of type constructors with a type family:

```
type family Iterate n f x where
  Iterate Z     f x = x
  Iterate (S n) f x = f (Iterate n f x)
```

For example, `Iterate (S (S Z)) [] Int` reduces to `[[Int]]`.

We don't use instances here, since the desired functionality can be achieved by simply writing functions.

```
fmapN :: Functor f => Sing (S n) -> (a -> b) -> f (Iterate n f a) -> f (Iterate n f b)
fmapN (SS SZ)     f = fmap f
fmapN (SS (SS n)) f = fmap (fmapN (SS n) f)

traverseN :: (Applicative f, Traversable t) => Sing (S n) -> (a -> f b) -> t (Iterate n t a) -> f (t (Iterate n t b))
traverseN (SS SZ)     f = traverse f
traverseN (SS (SS n)) f = traverse (traverseN (SS n) f)

foldMapN :: (Monoid m, Foldable f) => Sing (S n) -> (a -> m) -> f (Iterate n f a) -> m
foldMapN (SS SZ)     f = foldMap f
foldMapN (SS (SS n)) f = foldMap (foldMapN (SS n) f)
```

Some testing:

```
> traverseN (sing :: SLit 3) putStrLn [[["foo"]]]
foo
[[[()]]]
> fmapN (sing :: SLit 5) (+10) [[[[[0]]]]]
[[[[[10]]]]]
```

`sing :: SLit n` is a shorthand notation here for `Nat` singletons. [`sing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-1.1.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:SingI) comes from `Data.Singletons`, and it polymorphically creates singleton values based on the provided type annotations. `SLit` is a type synonym from `Data.Nat` which makes use of GHC's [type literals](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/GHC-TypeLits.html).

We could also write out the `Nat` singletons without sugar; for example, `SS (SS (SS SZ))` corresponds to `sing :: SLit 3`. In general, we can use the `Lit n` shorthand on the type level and `sing :: SLit n` on the term level.

Comment: I see you are counting from one -- any particular reason?

Comment: @chi if we count from zero, then we have the identity function for the `fmapN` zero case, which means the `f` type constructor doesn't appear in the return type, which results in ambiguous class constraints. We also get ambiguous types for non-zero cases, because `f` only appears inside a type family in the return type. It's better to always have something to `fmap` over. The same thing applies to `traverseN` and `foldMapN`.